# Error with javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElement

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm writing a telegram bot and started connecting the database (postgresql)
configured the connection and created the database
and and I get this error : `Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElement`

application.yml

```
spring:
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
    username: postgres
    password: 123456789
    jpa:
      hibernate:
        ddl-auto: update
      show-sql: true
      database: postgresql
      database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect


debug: true
logging:
  level:
    root: INFO
    org.springframework.web: INFO
    your.package: INFO
  file:
    name: logs/file.log
  pattern:
    file: "%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %5p --- [%t] %c{1} : %m%n"
```

main service

```
import com.telegram.bot.config.TelegramBotConfig;
import com.telegram.bot.model.User;
import com.telegram.bot.model.UserRepository;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.bots.TelegramLongPollingBot;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.methods.commands.SetMyCommands;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.methods.send.SendMessage;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.objects.Message;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.objects.Update;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.objects.commands.BotCommand;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.objects.commands.scope.BotCommandScopeDefault;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.exceptions.TelegramApiException;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Component
@Slf4j
public class TelegramBot extends TelegramLongPollingBot {

    final TelegramBotConfig config;

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository repository;
    public TelegramBot(TelegramBotConfig config) {
        this.config = config;
        List<BotCommand> listCommands = new ArrayList<>();

        //TODO delete this lists
        listCommands.add(new BotCommand("/mydata", "get your data stored"));
        listCommands.add(new BotCommand("/deletedata", "delete my data "));
        listCommands.add(new BotCommand("/settings", "set your preferences"));
        try{
            this.execute(new SetMyCommands(listCommands, new BotCommandScopeDefault(), null));
        } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
            log.error("error setting bot`s command list " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpdateReceived(Update update) {
        if (update.hasMessage() && update.getMessage().hasText()) {
            String messageText = update.getMessage().getText();
            long chatId = update.getMessage().getChatId();
            //TODO add new positions for menu
            switch (messageText) {
                case "/start":
                    registerUser(update.getMessage());
                    startCommandReceived(chatId, update.getMessage().getChat().getFirstName());
                    break;
                case "/help":
                    sendMessage(chatId, HELP_TEXT);
                    break;
                default: sendMessage(chatId, "sorry, command was not recognized");
                log.info("command was not recognized: " + messageText);
            }
        }
    }

    private void registerUser(Message message) {
        if(repository.findById(message.getChatId()).isEmpty()){
            var chatId = message.getChat();
            User user = new User();
            user.setName(chatId.getUserName());
            user.setRegisteredAt(LocalDateTime.now());

            repository.save(user);
            log.info("user save " + user);
        }
    }

    private void startCommandReceived(long chatId, String firstName) {
        String answer = "Hi " + firstName + " nice to meet you♥ and welcome to my information bot";
        sendMessage(chatId, answer);
    }

    private void sendMessage(long chatId, String textToSend) {
        SendMessage sendMessage = new SendMessage();
        sendMessage.setChatId(chatId);
        sendMessage.setText(textToSend);

        try {
            execute(sendMessage);
        } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
            log.error("Error occurred: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

and

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.telegram.bot</groupId>
    <artifactId>TelegramCVBot</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <name>TelegramCVBot</name>
    <description>TelegramCVBot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <telegram.version>6.8.0</telegram.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.telegram</groupId>
            <artifactId>telegrambots</artifactId>
            <version>${telegram.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.7.1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                    <executable>true</executable>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I don't use XmlElement anywhere... What is the problem ?

I thought there was a problem connecting to the database.

Comment: I tried to connect another database but got the same error

Comment: Moreover, in other projects I connected the database in the same way and there was no such error

Comment: look at the entire stacktrace. The Bean that fails to instantiate is a part of hibernate, and you are using hibernate

Comment: @Stultuske can you tell me more details, please ?

Comment: no, because I don't know what else is in the stacktrace.

Answer (score 1):

I fix problem

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```